# c++ equivalent to for calloc and declaring space for array variables

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I'm new to programming and I'm converting a code from C to C++

I need to declare space for array variables and have the following code in C:

```
r = calloc(MAXRAY+1, sizeof(double *));
for (i=0; i<=MAXRAY; i++)
    r[i] = calloc(3, sizeof(double));
```

I don't necessarily understand what the code is saying and so I don't necessarily understand how to convert this to C++

Thanks

Comment: well it's necessary to understand the necessity of understanding the original C code before trying to convert it to C++. otherwise, how would you know the equivalent construct between the two languages?

Comment: obviously -------------

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above C code snippet allocates `MAXRAY + 1` * `sizeof(double*)` memory and then assigns the first memory address to `r`. Now inside the loop, it iterates over `MAXRAY + 1` locations and allocates further `3 * sizeof(double)` for each `r[i]` entry.

You can simply use a `std::vector<std::array<double, 3>>` if `MAXRAY` can change. If it is a constant, use `std::array<std::array<double, 3>, MAXRAY+1>`.

```
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<std::array<double, 3>, MAXRAY+1> r ;
    for(auto i = 0u; i < r.size(); ++i)
        for(auto j = 0u; j < r[i].size(); ++j)
            r[i][j] = some_value ; // accessible.
}
```

In case however you decide to use `std::vector` of `std::array`s, then you need to insert them into the vector.

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::array<double, 3>> r ;
    for(auto i = 0u; i <= MAXRAY; ++i)
        r.push_back(std::array<double, 3>{ x, y, z });
}
```

Comment: If `MAXRAY` is constant you may still want to use a vector if it is large.

Answer (score -2):

What the code is doing is creating an array of arrays.  The variable r is an array of size MAXRAY+1 where each element is a pointer to an array of doubles that is size 3